# Pyqt 5 qlistwidgetitem id

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to add database objects to a QListwidget and add the id as hidden data.  Tue Qlistwidgetitem method setData only accept integers. Is there any possibility to add the database id? The used database is mongodb so the id contains letters and numbers.
Greetz Sven

Comment: The [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData) method does not only accept integers. It has two arguments: the first is a *role* (an `int`) and the second is a *value* (any python type). For custom data, use [`Qt.UserRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).

Comment: Hi. Thank you that worked. Have a nice evening.